# Monitor Google Spreadsheet cell value and undo an unwanted change

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, dom-events

This might seem a really stupid question but I hope not. I'm a nurse not a programmer so there's a huge amount that I don't (yet) understand.

There's an area at the bottom right of Google spreadsheets that seems to store the original value of a selected cell until the user taps Enter or clicks out of the cell. I assume it is used to assess if the cell has been edited by the user.

Would it be possible to access that data to record the value of a cell prior to edit? If so... how?

I don't know what the area is properly called but if I right click it and select "Inspect Element" this is highlighted:

```
<div class="waffle-formula-container" style dir="ltr">L</div>
```

The cell I selected contained the letter 'L' so I could figure out the last bit but what's a waffle-formula-container?  Googling that phrase returned a lot of advice on keeping waffles fresh but not much else of use.

I've starred issues [200](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&q=200&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&id=200) & [1200](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&q=1200&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&id=1200) which are related but it's been months now and  there seem to be no new developments so I'm trying to think outside the box.

I don't even know enough to know what tags to apply so I'd welcome advice on that alone.

Comment: A `class` attribute on an element is used to group it with like or similar elements for some reason (styling, for example, or for selecting elements by Javascript so you can work on them). (An `id` points to a *specific* element and should never indicate a grouping or be reused on a page.) So `waffle-formula-container` just refers to the fact it belongs to that group, in which Google is doing something with it. Are you trying to record changes to a spreadsheet so you can undo those changes? Can you explain what you're trying to do ultimately?

Comment: I edited the question after reviewing the links and reading what you're trying to do, which is related to Javascript DOM events, not really HTML. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Thank you for changing the tags Jared and for the explanation. Yes, I'm trying to come up with a way to undo unwanted changes, for instance if a user accidentally makes an entry on the wrong row. This is easily done in person by clicking undo, using Ctrl Z or even reloading a previous version from the revision history but I'd like to monitor for errors and resolve them programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments on other answers it looks like you are trying to emulate per-row permissions. Given the current limitations it may be better to look for alternative solutions, such as building a webapp using Google Apps Script that accepts and stores the data. This would give you full control over access permissions, etc.

Comment: Hi Eric, per=row permissions is exactly what I need. Thanks for the webapp idea - I tried it before but failed due to limited knowledge and services at that time. However things have moved on and now that we can run a webapp as the effective user, I might be able to work something out. Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is not much you can do apart from starring Issue 200. 
However, there is a workaround that has been discussed earlier

Use the onOpen call to store a copy of the spreadsheet in an array. So, on each onEdit, you have access to the old value and the new value. And within your onEdit, sync the array back with the data from the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks Srik. I read about that workaround but unfortunately it wouldn't be practical in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want to access this 'previous state's but if you need to see it  'manually' this feature is already built into the spreadsheet application with the revision history. This is a very powerful feature although not accessible by script:  every change is highlighted and you can even see who made the change :-)

Comment: Thanks Serge. What I'd like is the ability to automate the undo call when my script detects that a user has editted someone else's row. I anticipate the problem arising in a project I'm developing. The revision history forms part of my current workaround solution but I'm hoping someday not to have to rely on manual input to rectify the problem.